# Is there a prime every year if YYYYMMDD is treated as a base-$10$ number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, recreational-mathematics

As we approach the end of the year, I thought about the appearance of primes in calendar dates as a recreational problem. Consider the number formed by concatenating the digits of a date in the form YYYYMMDD. For example 31-Dec-2019 will be written as $20191231$.

I was investigating if the number YYYYMMDD is prime. I checked for the next hundred thousand years and found that each year has between a minimum of $1$ for the year $5771237$ and a maximum of $37$ primes for the year $450060$. I could not yet find a single year which did not have a prime.

> **Conjecture**: There is at least one prime every year.
>
> **Update**: The year $27789755$ is the smallest year which has no prime.

What is the smallest counter example?

Also $37$ primes occurring in the year $450060$ because it implies that the interval $(4500600001, 4500601231)$ contains at least $37$  primes. Upon checking, it turns out this interval contains $77$ primes which is quite a dense for a short interval between two large numbers.

Comment: If you checked $YYYY$ for $0000$ through $9999$ you have shown that every year (if you truncate to the last four digits to fit $YYYYMMDD$) will have a prime.  The proofs in the answers involve years that have more than four digits and have more digits $Y$ than you have specified.  I don't say this as a criticism, but as a point that exactly how you ask the question can change the answer.

Comment: @TravisWillse That’s enough primes for our lifetimes!

Comment: @TravisWillse I guess in reality we may not have to go that far. The first occurrence of a year with only $1$ prime is $5771237$ so a year with zero primes may not be too far out.

Comment: @TravisWillse Got it! The year $27789755$ is the smallest year which has no prime.

Comment: The next year with no primes is actually $13446204$. It happens that $134462040931$ is prime, but there is no 31st of September, of course. I note also that the year $450060$ has only $35$ primes, although $4500600431$ and $4500600631$ are both prime. Did you test the days of the month precisely?

Comment: I should be more careful writing right before bed: Heuristically we expect failure to occur $\color{red}{\textrm{with characteristic probability} \frac{1}{e}}$ around years with value $e^{365} / 10^\color{red}{4} \approx 10^{\color{red}{155}}$.

Comment: @nickgard I used the system generated date, so unless the system gives a impossible date for the future, it should be fine.

Comment: A (crude) heuristic predicts a first failure around $4.7 \cdot 10^6$, which is within an order of magnitude of the exact values reported by nickgard and Nilotpal Kanti Sinha.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is false, as you can construct sequences of composite numbers of arbitrary length $n$, e.g.,
$$(n+1)! + 2, \ldots, (n + 1)! + (n + 1) :$$ Pick such a sequence of length at least $19999$, so that it contains a subsequence of consecutive numbers ending in $0000, \ldots, 9999$. Then, the first number in that subsequence is $10\,000 \cdot y$ for some integer $y$, and all the numbers given by date strings from the year $y$ are composite.

Answer (score 18):

Your conjecture is false.

Let $S=\left\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_{366}\right\}$ be the set of all numbers of the form MMDD, including $229$.
We can restate your problem in the following marginally weaker form (it's weaker since not all years are leap years):

> For every $k$, at least one of the numbers $$10000k+s$$ for $s\in S$ is a prime number.

However, this can easily be proven false. If we take $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_{366}$ to be $366$ distinct prime numbers, different from $2$ and $5$, by the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), there exists a $Y$ such that $$Y\equiv-s_1\cdot10000^{-1}\pmod{p_1}$$ $$Y\equiv-s_2\cdot10000^{-1}\pmod{p_2}$$ $$\vdots$$ $$Y\equiv-s_{366}\cdot10000^{-1}\pmod{p_{366}}$$ For this year $Y$, every single number $10000Y+s_i$ that we can generate will be divisible by the corresponding $p_i$ (while at the same time being much bigger than it), meaning that this year will have no primes.

---

Here's an alternate proof, much more technical, but much more faster. If every year had a prime, then $\pi(n)\in O(n)$, which is false by the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

Comment: This is nice. An alternative might be to check the year $Y=1231!$ for then $MMDD$ will alwyas be a non-trivial factor of $Y$.

Comment: This looks similar to [Erdos's method of covering systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system#Primefree_sequences) for generating prime-free sequences.

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha Jyrki’s method is pretty much what Travis Willse did. I suggest you give the accepted answer to him.

Comment: The basic idea in the two solutions are the same, but Jyrki's observation leads to a *much* better bound than my solution: $1231!$ has $3\,272$ digits, whereas $20000! + 10^5$ (produced using the sequence in my answer without any additional observations) has $77\,338$ digits.

Comment: If we're going to use $1231!$, we can also just multiply the largest prime powers contained there is, thus $2^{10}×3^6×5^4×7^3×11^2×13^2×$(squares of more primes up to $31$)$×37×$(remaining primes up to $1231$).

Comment: @OscarLanzi For that matter by the same reasoning we can just take the $\textrm{lcm}$ of the smallest prime factors of $101, \ldots, 131, 201, \ldots ,1231$. A quick script finds this number to have just $168$ digits, short enough to write down, which isn't bad for a cheap computation---10195786957875821444345027559223862895695570587202703712 \\ \qquad 45663038946624297463506225005754546690502456396108946978 \\ \qquad\qquad  43996095129242049481585843767583543973383881510424445610$$---but which is still far short of the apparently optimal $8$-digit solutions.